# kendo inline editor issue in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, kendo-ui

I am using kendo inline editor in my application.I am not specifying height.
   I gave css like

```css
.k-editor-inline {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    background: none;
    font-family:'Century Gothic';
    font-size:13px;
    border-color:#f0b14e;
}
```

In firefox initially It is showing very less height(almost 0 px)
how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `min-height` attribute to the minimum desired height;

Example:

```
.k-editor-inline {
    min-height: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    background: none;
    font-family:'Century Gothic';
    font-size:13px;
    border-color:#f0b14e;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/T65Jk/